# Bash shave a first and/or last character from string, but only if it is a certain character

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In bash I need to shave a first and/or last character from string, but only if it is a certain character.

If I have        |   I need

```
/foo/bar/hah/   =>   foo/bar/hah

foo/bar/hah     =>   foo/bar/hah
```

You can downvote me for not listing everything I've tried.  But the fact is I've tried at least 35 differents sed strings and bash character stuff, many of which was from stack overflow.  I simply cannot get this to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what's the problem with the simple one?

```
sed "s/^\///;s/\/$//"
```

Output is

```
foo/bar/hah
foo/bar/hah
```

Comment: No need for `g` flag if your regex is anchored at the beginning or end

Comment: Didn't know it, i thought i have to use it if i want to remove all occurrences, fixed it

Comment: You do need it to remove 2 or more occurrences, but with an anchor there can be at most 1 match.

Comment: @glennjackman You need the `g` if you combine your pattern to one like this: `sed "s/^\/\|\/$//g"`.  To save some escaping of `/` do: `sed 's!^/\|/$!!g'`

Answer (score 4):

In pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
$ var=/foo/bar/hah/
$ var=${var%/}
$ echo ${var#/}
foo/bar/hah
$
```

Check [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ sed -r 's@(^/|/$)@@g' file
```

Comment: Some variation of your `sed`: `sed 's@^/\|/$@@g'`

Answer (score 1):

How about simply this:

```
echo "$x" | sed -e 's:^/::' -e 's:/$::'
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to @sputnick's answer and from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/89999), here's a function that would do it:

```
STR="/foo/bar/etc/";
STRB="foo/bar/etc";

function trimslashes {
    STR="$1"
    STR=${STR#"/"}
    STR=${STR%"/"}
    echo "$STR"
}

trimslashes $STR
trimslashes $STRB

# foo/bar/etc
# foo/bar/etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '/foo/bar/hah/' | sed 's#^/##' | sed 's#/$##'
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming the `/` character is the only one you're trying to remove, then `sed -E 's_^[/](.*)_\1_'` should do the job:

```
$ echo "$var1"; echo "$var2"
/foo/bar/hah
foo/bar/hah


$ echo "$var1" | sed -E 's_^[/](.*)_\1_'
foo/bar/hah


$ echo "$var2" | sed -E 's_^[/](.*)_\1_'
foo/bar/hah
```

if you also need to replace other characters at the start of the line, add it to the `[/]` class.  for example, if you need to replace `/` or `-`, it would be `sed -E 's_^[/-](.*)_\1_'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
echo "/foo/bar/hah/" | awk '{gsub(/^\/|\/$/,"")}1'
foo/bar/hah
```